# Using PHP how to convert csv file

Tags: php, csv

i have a csv file where the header line is in row 1 not row 0 how can i convert a csv in this situation. I have seen good versions of converting a csv file where the header row is at row[0] as

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $data;
}
```

please can someone assist me in the situation where row[1] is the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
            function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
            {
            if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
                return FALSE;

            $header = NULL;
            $data = array();
            if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
            {
                $i=0;
                while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
                {
                    if($i==0)
                    {
                      $i++;
                      continue;   //SKIP FIRST ROW
                    }
                    if(!$header)
                        $header = $row;
                    else
                        $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
            return $data;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, if the headers are on row 1, what is on row 0?  Is it blank?

In any case:

```
$i = 0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1) {
        continue; // Or do something else?
    } elseif ($i == 2) {
        $header = $row; // Get the headers on row 1
    } else {
        $data[] = $row; // Get the data on row 2 and above
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

var_dump($data[1]); // This is the header

for ($i = 2, $j = count($data); $i < $j; $i++) {
    var_dump($data[ $i ]); // Each row of data
}
```

Comment: use $i++ before continue otherwise $i will always be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fgetcsv and store results into an array like this

```
$file = fopen("path/to/csv","r");
$list=array();

//saving in list 
while ($row=fgetcsv($file)) {
  $list[]=$row;
}
```

then you can run a for loop starting $i = 2